# vb3: change to locale date format

Tags: vb6, vb5

I have an error in vb3 code which I set date as 31/12/2200 and jump an error telling the format is not like locale machine.

The solution is to set manually 12/31/2200 but what I am interested is to get the locale of the machine to make it automatically.

how can I change to locale date in vb3?

Comment: variable = "31/12/2000" should be "12/31/2000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with VB3. I haven't seen that in many years now. I can give you something that will work in VB5/VB6. I do not know how well it will transfer to VB3. Hopefully if it needs work you can translate it to VB3 or find someone that can. You'll want to add appropriate error handling.

```
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F ' short date format string
Private Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20 ' long date format string

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strMsg As String

    strMsg = "Short Date Format: " & FormatShortDate(DateTime.Now)
    strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & "Long Date Format: " & FormatLongDate(DateTime.Now)

    MsgBox strMsg

End Sub

Private Function FormatShortDate(ByVal vDate As Date) As String
    Dim strShortDateFormat As String
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim strReturn As String

    'Get short date format
    strShortDateFormat = Space(255)
    lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, strShortDateFormat, Len(strShortDateFormat))
    strShortDateFormat = Left(strShortDateFormat, lngRet - 1)

    strReturn = Format$(vDate, strShortDateFormat)

    FormatShortDate = strReturn

End Function

Private Function FormatLongDate(ByVal vDate As Date) As String
    Dim strLongDateFormat As String
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim strReturn As String

    'Get long date format
    strLongDateFormat = Space(255)
    lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLONGDATE, strLongDateFormat, Len(strLongDateFormat))
    strLongDateFormat = Left(strLongDateFormat, lngRet - 1)

    strReturn = Format$(vDate, strLongDateFormat)

    FormatLongDate = strReturn

End Function
```

Comment: My recollection of vb3 is that, as a 16bit app development tool, it was not itself locale aware, and you generally could not make the Windows api calls, as @jac has done here, to perform these locale operations.